# Utilizzo del verbo fare col significato di scegliere/preferire

Tags: word-usage, verbs, grammar

Mi chiedevo se l'utilizzo del verbo fare col significato di scegliere/preferire sia o meno corretto?

Es. 'Quanti ne vuoi?' 'Farei cinque'

Anche con accezione di svogliatezza nello scegliere una cosa

Es. 'Dovresti mettere una maglia bianca non rossa' 'Farò bianca allora'

Comment: Questo uso, come viene mostrato in questi esempi, non mi è particolarmente familiare (ma ovviamente non vuol dire molto). Se ho capito bene cosa intendi, io direi “Diciamo cinque” o “Diciamo bianca, allora” (o forse anche “facciamo”). Forse sono usi regionali diversi? Posso chiederti di che parte d'Italia sei?

Comment: Ah, attento/a: “accezione”, non “accezzione”.

Comment: sono dall'emilia romagna

Comment: *Fare* può svolgere la funzione di verbo vicario, assumendo il significato di qualsiasi verbo che designi un'azione; normalmente in questa funzione segue il verbo che sostituisce: se hai qlco. da dirmi, fallo (= dimmelo) subito. (Sabatini Coletti)

Comment: in questo caso non segue il verbo che sostituisce

Comment: Quante ne vuoi? Farei (ne voglio) cinque.

Comment: Dovresti mettere una maglia bianca non rossa' 'Farò (metterò) bianca allora'

Comment: @Hachi, è un'ipotesi interessante, ma non ne sono sicurissimo, perché a parte che come dicevo nel mio commento in quelle situazioni si usano anche altri verbi, lo stesso “fare” si può usare in modi non compatibili con una funzione di verbo vicario (appunto “Quante ne vuoi?” “Facciamo cinque”).

Comment: L’uso di fare come “sostituto” del verbo di riferimento è molto comune, almeno nelle regioni del nord, ma penso in tutta Italia. È sicuramente un uso informale, probabilmente di origine dialettale, ma come dice il Sabini Coletti, abbastanza diffuso da essere elencato in un dizionario.

Comment: quindi seconondo te hachi é corretto?

Comment: @Hachi: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/fare-finestra-di-approfondimento_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/ --> cerca "verbo vicario". Questo uso è standard, ma non sono per niente sicura che sia lo stesso di quello che chiede l'OP.

Comment: @Hachi: Quello che ha suscitato il dubbio che ho espresso nel commento precedente è fare il paragone con una delle mie lingue. In catalano il verbo "fer" ("fare") può avere il significato di "fornire", quindi come risposta alla domanda "Quants en vols?" ("Quanti ne vuoi?") potrei dire "Fem-ne cinc" ("Facciamone cinque").

Comment: @Charo - il paragone con l’uso in catalano non mi sembra pertinente. L’uso di “fare” nell’ accezione posta dal OP è quella di cui parla il Sabatini Coletti il quale chiarisce che “fare”, nell’uso citato,  può “assumere il significato di qualsiasi verbo che designi un'azione”. Ripeto: è un uso informale moto comune.

Comment: @Hachi: Come Charo, anch'io non sono persuaso che “fare” abbia qui la funzione che dici. In ogni caso, come spiegheresti espressioni del tipo “facciamo cinque” o “facciamo così” (vedi commento qui sopra) in cui sicuramente non è un verbo vicario perché cambia anche la persona del soggetto? (“Quanti ne _vuoi_?” “_Facciamo_ cinque”)

Comment: @Hachi:   Inoltre, per quanto ne so, l'uso dell'analogo al verbo "fare" come verbo vicario è comune in parecchie lingue romanze, quindi non credo si tratti di qualcosa di origine "dialettale". E non capisco neanche perché dovrebbe considerarsi come informale.